# Mysql партицирование. Как разделить таблицу по списку и дате?

Tags: mysql, partition

Всем привет. Есть следующая таблица (упрощенная):

```
CREATE TABLE `routes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`createdTimezoneOffset` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`created`,`archive`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1014699 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Необходимо разделить таблицу следующим образом:

Раздел: Архив = 0
Подраздел: Год создания

Раздел: Архив = 1
Подраздел: Год создания

Делаю так:

```
ALTER TABLE routes PARTITION BY LIST (archive)
SUBPARTITION BY HASH (YEAR(created))
(
    PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (0)
    (
        SUBPARTITION s0,
        SUBPARTITION s1,
        SUBPARTITION s2,
        SUBPARTITION s3
    ),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (1)
    (
        SUBPARTITION s4,
        SUBPARTITION s5,
        SUBPARTITION s6,
        SUBPARTITION s7
    ) 
);
```

И все вроде бы работает. Но когда делаю выборку по периоду поля created - читаются все разделы.

```
Пример:  EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM routes WHERE archive = 1 AND created >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Исходя из документации - понимаю почему.
Как правильно разделить таблицу таким образом, чтобы запрос выше брал определенную часть таблицы ?

Comment: В показанной структуре отсутствует поле `archive`. PS. Для показанного запроса партиционирование - явно излишне, достаточно индекса.

Comment: Поле archive существует. Когда укорачивал таблицу, то удалил его случайно.
Мой запрос - просто пример, который служит для того, чтобы показать, что при поиске по диапазону дат читаются все части таблицы.
Мне же нужно, чтобы бралась только нужная партиция.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено.
Работает так, как надо, оставлю это здесь:

```
ALTER TABLE routes PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (archive, created)
(
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0, MAXVALUE),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1, '2019-01-01'),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1, '2020-01-01'),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (1, '2020-06-01'),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (1, MAXVALUE)
);
```